# Modern way of writing native Win32 applications

Tags: winapi, native

Title pretty much explains the question, but nevertheless I'll expand on it.

I want to "brush up" my native skills a tad, and therefore am wondering what are the current state-of-the-art approaches? Plain C or C++? C with some libraries I don't even know of or C++ with MFC/WTL/OWL?

Comment: MFC was never state of the art. State of the ark perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

10 years ago, right before .net 1.0 was released, the "tech visionaries" promptly predicted the eventual demise of COM/C++, but today COM/C++ is well alive. look no furhter than this page on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/

The first item under Top Windows Solutions is Win32/COM development (not MFC, which few people care about).

I believe you'll do well by (re- ?)acquaint yourself with Win32/COM/C++ (well, I mean win64, as everyone can see 64-bit apps are going mainstream these days).

On a side note, may I ask why you want to brush up your native dev skills? i'm asking because i had the same urge last year and spent nearly 8 months on some Win32 API projects (didnt get much done in COM though, but I think with Windows 8 coming up soon, COM will take on a second life).

Comment: I'd want to do native windows development for speed. WPF in .NET is so painfully slow. Pretty... but slow. :)